# Different aimed chunks of code in a unique flow

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code.

**first chunk**

```
data <- data %>% mutate(`Age (years)_cat` = case_when(`Age (years)`< 50 ~ 'young',
                                                      TRUE ~ 'old'))
```

**second chunk**

```
data %>%
  mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death'))%$%
  table(Death, Treatment, `Age (years)_cat`)
```

I have suited the code as follows since I needed **to not execute** the command in the second chunk on the first one. If I would write a **unique dplyr code** that respects such an issue, would it be somehow possible?

How should the code be set, in that case? If not are there some other altneratives?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "not execute the command in the second chink of the first one"? Perhaps showing a little bit of sample input and the desired code would help clarify. If you simply don't want to execute the second chunk of code, you can not run, comment it out, or fully delete it.

Comment: Or do you mean something like, you don't want to create a `Death` variable for rows where `Age (years)_cat == "young"`? Or maybe you want to exclude `Age (years)_cat == "old"` rows from the table in the second chunk? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use parentheses:

```
(data <- data %>% mutate(`Age (years)_cat` = case_when(`Age (years)`< 50 ~ 'young',
                                                      TRUE ~ 'old'))) %>%
 mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death')) %$%
 table(Death, Treatment, `Age (years)_cat`)
```

Another option is to use `assign`:

```
data %>% mutate(`Age (years)_cat` = case_when(`Age (years)`< 50 ~ 'young',
                                                      TRUE ~ 'old')) %>%
 assign(x='data',value=.,.GlobalEnv) %>%
 mutate(Death = ifelse(Death == 0, 'No Death', 'Death'))%$%
 table(Death, Treatment, `Age (years)_cat`)
```